# Separar números de una lista con cadenas

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

Tengo esta lista:

```
['<td>1\n', '<td>3\n', '<td>4\n', '<td>5\n', '<td>7\n', '<td>10\n', '<td>13\n', '<td>17\n', '<td>23\n', '<td>34\n', '<td>43\n', '<td>61\n', '<td>75\n', '<td>156\n', '<td>201\n', '<td>238\n', '<td>342\n', '<td>434\n', '<td>537\n', '<td>632\n', '<td>746\n', '<td>922\n', '<td>1142\n', '<td>1306\n', '<td>1610\n', '<td>1909\n', '<td>2139\n', '<td>2449\n', '<td>2738\n', '<td>3031\n', '<td>3404\n', '<td>3737\n', '<td>4161\n', '<td>4471\n', '<td>4815\n', '<td>5116\n', '<td>5546\n', '<td>5972\n', '<td>6501\n', '<td>6927\n', '<td>7213\n', '<td>7525\n', '<td>7917\n', '<td>8273\n', '<td>8807\n', '<td>9252\n', '<td>9730\n', '<td>10 088\n', '<td>10 507\n', '<td>10 832\n', '<td>11 296\n', '<td>11 812\n', '<td>12 306\n', '<td>12 858\n', '<td>13 331\n', '<td>13 813\n', '<td>14 365\n', '<td>15 135\n', '<td>16 023\n', '<td>17 008\n', '<td>18 435\n', '<td>19 663\n', '<td>20 643\n', '<td>22 016\n']
```

Y quiero tener una lista pero solo con los numeros, quitando todas esas etiquetas de HTML.

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado? Revisa expresiones regulares para python, la librería `re`.

Comment: Ya las he visto, gracias, es lo que necesitaba

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te dejo un ejemplo de como lo podrías realizar. Tienes una cadena en donde te interesa extraer lo que esta dentro de `AAA` y `ZZZ`:

```
import re

text = 'gfgfdAAA1234ZZZuijjk'
m = re.search('AAA(.+?)ZZZ', text)
if m:
    found = m.group(1)
```

Llevandolo a tu problema una manera sería:

```
lista = ['<td>1\n', '<td>3\n', '<td>4\n', '<td>5\n', '<td>7\n', '<td>10\n', '<td>13\n', '<td>17\n', '<td>23\n', '<td>34\n', '<td>43\n', '<td>61\n', '<td>75\n', '<td>156\n', '<td>201\n', '<td>238\n', '<td>342\n', '<td>434\n', '<td>537\n', '<td>632\n', '<td>746\n', '<td>922\n', '<td>1142\n', '<td>1306\n', '<td>1610\n', '<td>1909\n', '<td>2139\n', '<td>2449\n', '<td>2738\n', '<td>3031\n', '<td>3404\n', '<td>3737\n', '<td>4161\n', '<td>4471\n', '<td>4815\n', '<td>5116\n', '<td>5546\n', '<td>5972\n', '<td>6501\n', '<td>6927\n', '<td>7213\n', '<td>7525\n', '<td>7917\n', '<td>8273\n', '<td>8807\n', '<td>9252\n', '<td>9730\n', '<td>10 088\n', '<td>10 507\n', '<td>10 832\n', '<td>11 296\n', '<td>11 812\n', '<td>12 306\n', '<td>12 858\n', '<td>13 331\n', '<td>13 813\n', '<td>14 365\n', '<td>15 135\n', '<td>16 023\n', '<td>17 008\n', '<td>18 435\n', '<td>19 663\n', '<td>20 643\n', '<td>22 016\n']

lista_new = []
for i in lista:
    lista_new.append(re.search('<td>(.+?)\n',i).group(1))
```

Revisa la documentación de `re`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html.